# How to calculate the determinant using Laplace

Tags: matrices

How to calculate the determinant using Laplace?
$$
det \begin{bmatrix}
       a1 & a2 & a3 & a4 & a5           \\[0.3em]
       b1 & b2 & b3 & b4 & b5        \\[0.3em]
       c1 & c2 & 0& 0& 0\\[0.3em]
       d1 & d2 & 0& 0& 0\\[0.3em]
       e1 & e2 & 0 & 0& 0\\[0.3em]
     \end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Laplace expansion on the $5$th row:

$\displaystyle\begin{vmatrix}
       a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & a_4 & a_5           \\[0.3em]
       b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & b_4 & b_5        \\[0.3em]
       c_1 & c_2 & 0& 0& 0\\[0.3em]
       d_1 & d_2 & 0& 0& 0\\[0.3em]
       e_1 & e_2 & 0 & 0& 0\\[0.3em]
     \end{vmatrix} = e_1\begin{vmatrix}
        a_2 & a_3 & a_4 & a_5           \\[0.3em]
        b_2 & b_3 & b_4 & b_5        \\[0.3em]
        c_2 & 0& 0& 0\\[0.3em]
        d_2 & 0& 0& 0\\[0.3em]
        \end{vmatrix}-e_2\begin{vmatrix}
        a_1 & a_3 & a_4 & a_5           \\[0.3em]
        b_1 & b_3 & b_4 & b_5        \\[0.3em]
        c_1 & 0& 0& 0\\[0.3em]
        d_1 & 0& 0& 0\\[0.3em]
        \end{vmatrix}$

$\displaystyle=e_1d_2\begin{vmatrix}
         a_3 & a_4 & a_5           \\[0.3em]
         b_3 & b_4 & b_5        \\[0.3em]
         0& 0& 0\\[0.3em]
                \end{vmatrix}-e_2d_1\begin{vmatrix}
         a_3 & a_4 & a_5           \\[0.3em]
         b_3 & b_4 & b_5        \\[0.3em]
         0& 0& 0\\[0.3em]
        \end{vmatrix}=0$

Or more conveniently one can directly expand the $4$th and the $5$th row together

$\displaystyle\begin{vmatrix}
       a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & a_4 & a_5           \\[0.3em]
       b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & b_4 & b_5        \\[0.3em]
       c_1 & c_2 & 0& 0& 0\\[0.3em]
       d_1 & d_2 & 0& 0& 0\\[0.3em]
       e_1 & e_2 & 0 & 0& 0\\[0.3em]
     \end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
        e_1 & d_1            \\[0.3em]
        e_2 & d_2         \\[0.3em]
        \end{vmatrix}\begin{vmatrix}
         a_3 & a_4 & a_5           \\[0.3em]
         b_3 & b_4 & b_5        \\[0.3em]
         0& 0& 0\\[0.3em]
        \end{vmatrix}=0$